# Using custom Mesos roles in DC/OS on AWS

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I'm trying to setup DC/OS on AWS with different resource roles (I don't want nodes reserved for Apache Cassandra used by other things). I know in theory how to do it in a plain Mesos that I set up manually (https://support.mesosphere.com/hc/en-us/articles/206474745-How-to-reserve-resources-for-certain-frameworks-in-Mesos-cluster-), but I don't know how to do it in a DC/OS cloud installation. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

DC/OS neither facilitates, nor prohibits services (aka frameworks) to register with a custom role. I'm not sure how to tell Cassandra to register under special role, Jenkins for example exposes it in its configurations (see screenshot below). In short, check with your framework, how to register in a custom role, DC/OS does not restrict this.

If you want to configure role-specific things, like weights or quota, just talk directly to Mesos, which is accessible via `/mesos`, DC/OS does not prohibit it either.

[image: Jenkins role configurations]